# PHP Appends X-Msg to link

Tags: php, html, forms, email, hyperlink

I am trying to make an online system where people can send leads html emails, from within the system...

I have everything working except for when I put in links with the rich text editor, and everything looks fine in the source, but when I look at the email in my inbox, the link doesnt work and has changed to:

> x-msg://30/%22http://example.com/%22

which I dont understand...

I think it is a problem with the html post function as I am submitting it through and html form with `$_POST` method...  And when I echo the statement on the next page, the link is *`http://workwithmandy.co/%22http://phobes.com/%22`*, which is weird because the root of the site that the system is on is *`http://workwithmandy.co/`* .

Any Ideas on why this is??

**Here is the form:**

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="form" id="sendemailform">
          <fieldset>
          <div class="emailtablecontainer">
          <table width="525" border="0" cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td><label>To:</label></td>
    <td><select data-placeholder="Select Lead(s) To Email..." multiple="true" class="chzn-container-multi" name="selectleads"style="width:500px;">
            <?php
do {  
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_rsAllLeads['Email']?>"><?php echo $row_rsAllLeads['FullName']?></option>
            <?php
} while ($row_rsAllLeads = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAllLeads));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($rsAllLeads);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($rsAllLeads, 0);
      $row_rsAllLeads = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAllLeads);
  }
?>
          </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Subject:</label></td>
    <td><input class="inputs" name="subjectfield" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Message:</label></td>
    <td><textarea id="sendemailtextarea" name="messagefield"></textarea></td>
    <script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'sendemailtextarea',
    {
        toolbar : 'SendEmailToolbar'
    });
    </script>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<input class="submitemailbuttonsprite submitemailbutton1" name="submitemail" type="submit" value="Send Email(s)">
          </fieldset>
          <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form">
          </form>
```

**And Here Is The Actual Php Code:**

```
<?php
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {
    echo $_POST['messagefield'];
 $to = $_POST['selectleads'];
 $subject = $_POST['subjectfield'];
 $body = $_POST['messagefield'];
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "From: " . $row_rs_CurrentUser['FirstName'] . " " . $row_rs_CurrentUser['LastName'] . " <" . $row_rs_CurrentUser['Email'] . ">";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Im using CKeditor, and i tried it without the RTE and the same thing happened...  So its obviously not a problem with the RTE...  Any other tips?

Comment: Are you 10000% sure it's PHP adding those links and not the E-Mail client itself?

Comment: No, I'm not sure...  I am just about 75% sure that its not the Rich Text Editor, because i put <a href="http://www.amazon.com/">hello</a> in with a regular input, and it did the same thing...  But it could be the E-Mail client, however as you can see in the code, I am echoing the $_POST['message'] field before i send the email and it appears in the page, already screwed up...  So I think its either the PHP or the fact that im sending the data through a form...  I have tried both POST and GET methods, neither work...

Comment: I also just tried changing the form enctype...  No luck there either...  I think its encoding it so its url friendly somehow, which is changeing <a href> to %22 or something...  But thats just a theory...  im sure about it or how i would fix it...

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to answer the question. But it may help someone else in need.

This is not like PHP Prepends `x-msg://` to the email links.

Actually the Email Clients Prepends `x-msg://` to the link. Because they take a link without `http://` or `https://` as invalid URI. To make it valid they prepend `x-msg://` to the link.

So check if you have missed `http://` or `https://` in your href link.

Example:
This first example may not work fine:

```
<a href="www.example.com">www.example.com</a> // x:msg:// may be prepended by some of the email clients
```

This will surely work correctly:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">www.example.com</a> // x:msg:// will not be prepended by any email client
```